# clang-format for Eigen matrix initialization

Tags: c++, eigen, clang-format

To inialize for example `Eigen::Matrix3i` we can use syntax:

```
Eigen::Matrix3i T;
T << 1, 0, 0,
     0, 2, 0,
     0, 0, 3;
```

However, when using `clang-format` (3.6 in my case) with `Google` style this nice initialization turns into:

```
Eigen::Matrix3i T;
T << 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3;
```

Is there an easy way to avoid this? Is there a way to tell `clang-format` to skip something like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your only option is to use a rather ugly clang-format switching syntax:

```
Eigen::Matrix3i T;
// clang-format off
T << 1, 0, 0,
     0, 2, 0,
     0, 0, 3;
// clang-format on
```

Comment: Uglifying the code so the prettifier doesn't uglify it seems to be sort of invalidating the point though.

Comment: Ugh. Well, this is a solution, but yeah, I agree with @Cubic here. I will leave the question open for some time in case somebody comes up with something else. If this does not happen, I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: @Cubic yeah, I agree too, but this solution could be viable if you're forced to use two coding styles(e.g. for checkout and commits) and in similar situations

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this?

```cpp
Eigen::Matrix3i T;
T << 1, 0, 0, //
     0, 2, 0, //
     0, 0, 3; //
```

Comment: Same answer as others.

Comment: What do you mean? There is only one other answer and it's different than this.